# c# delete a List from a List<List<>>

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a  `List<List<Ricerca>>` where my object Ricerca has the following structure:

```
 public class Ricerca    {
    public int id;

    public double Altezza;
    public double lunghezza;
    }
```

I want to delete from the `List<List<Ricerca>>` all the lists that contain an OBJECT Ricerca with id present in a list of ids. The code I am using to do so follows but it's slow. Is there a better way? I wanted to use the linq but I can't figure out how.

```
public void CleanCombinations(ref List<List<Ricerca>> list,List<Combinazione> combs)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        bool remove = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < list[i].Count; k++)
        {
            foreach (Combinazione cbn in combs)
            {
                foreach (int ind in cbn.index)
                {
                    if (ind == list[i][k].id)
                    {
                        remove = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (remove)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The following Linq will do it.

```
var ids = new[] { 2, 3 };
list.RemoveAll(subList => subList.Any(item => ids.Contains(item.id)));
```

Comment: its shorter...but why is it any faster?

Comment: Should be - Linq was implemented by some very clever computer scientists to be highly optimised.

Comment: Micro optimizations. There is always something more significant to care about than performance of lists. Performance of databases for instance.

Comment: When you use `list.RemoveAll`, you will not need to pass it by reference.

Comment: @SteveJ: LINQ was optimised to be convenient and easy, not necessarily faster. It isn't magic and often won't be any faster than a basic well written for loop. In this case though one of the reasons it will be faster is because `Any` will stop iterating over `subList` as soon as it finds a single match - it knows any further checking is unnecessary. So if subList was 100 items long and the very first item matched the `Contains` part of the expression then it won't check the other 99 items. The OPs code doesn't have this early break as Ctznkane525 said in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Brevity of code will not help your computational problem.

As long as you have an unsorted list, the fastest search is going to be O(n), meaning worst case you have to iterate through all the items.

Now in your situation, you continue iterating after finding the value.  My recommendation would be to exit the loop when finding the item, so your average case becomes n/2 instead of n.

If you have many searches and the order of the items is not important, then the List is not a good choice.  I recommend using a dictionary where you can do a search by key in O(1).

If order of the items is important, then go with a SortedList.  You'll get O(log n) search.